# ifconfig/ip link show- how to get only Hardware interface

Tags: macos, ifconfig

How do you get only hardware interfaces

Tried:

```
ifconfig -a
ip link show
```

How do you get only local hardware interfaces using ifconfig/ip link show?

Like from my ifconfig I get(removed a lot):

```
en0: inet 192.168.0.146 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
utun0:
utun1:
utun2:
utun3:
utun4:
```

##### Update: I guess it is interfaces from previous Software Interface connections.

Then I investigated on the interface utun with lsof:

```
sudo lsof | grep utun

    identitys  577
    identitys  577
    identitys  577
    identitys  577
    identitys  577
```

Ok something called `identitys`, still thinking it is local to my computer until I found nmap tool:

```
sudo nmap -sn 192.168.0.127/24

Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.6
Host is up (0.13s latency).
MAC Address: <xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx> (Sonos)
... # And more
```

Turns out it is my Sonos speakers on the local Wifi network.

Why is ipconfig/if link show showing other Interfaces?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome, use `ip` instead: `ip link show`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that - I will update the question.

Comment: OP uses macOS and probably a wrapper [iproute2mac](https://github.com/brona/iproute2mac) which really doesn't help answering (see this SF question similar to the question here and its comments: https://serverfault.com/questions/1101318/list-hardware-network-interfaces-controllers . Also ifconfig on Linux doesn't display netmask in hex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-You can try using awk like this way!

```
ifconfig | awk '{print $1"\t"$7}' | grep eth0
```

or this another way...

```
ifconfig | awk '{print $1"\t"$7}'|grep eth0|awk '{print $2}'
```